# Uninstall .NET Core SDK 7.0

Tags: .net, .net-core, uninstallation

**Q)** How do I uninstall **.NET Core SDK 7.0.100-rc.2.22477.23**?

I'm trying to use the command-line tool `dotnet-core-uninstall` to uninstall it without success because of the message `[Cannot uninstall version 7.0.0 and above]`.

Even this command line failed:

```bash
michael@MichaelWorkBook dotnet-core-uninstall % ./dotnet-core-uninstall dry-run --sdk 7.0.100-rc.2.22477.23
Uninstallation not allowed. This tool cannot uninstall .NET Core SDKs with version 7.0.0 or above.
```

This is the tool [.NET uninstall tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=macos) I'm using to attempt the uninstall.

Additional Context: From a loose memory, I may have installed .NET SDK 7.0 via Visual Studio for Mac.  Version 7 release candidate 2 may accidentally have hurt my ability to compile my Azure functions project.

[image: screenshot of command line usage of dotnet-core-uninstall list]

Comment: Not very odd. Preliminary bits are only partially supported, or not supported at all. A few shell commands from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-macos#uninstall-net are enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### On MacOS

#### Radical

Delete the folder `usr/local/share/dotnet`.

#### Subtil

```bash
version="7.0.100-rc.2.22477.23"
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/$version
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/dotnet/host/fxr/$version
```